# How to make nav bar stick with scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having trouble finding out how to make the nav bar on my website stick to the left side when the user scrolls on the page.

Here is my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/2ud65fba/

HTML:

```
    <header>
    <div class="logo">
        <a href="index.html">
            <img src="img/logo.png"/>
        </a>
    </div><!-- end logo -->

    <div id="menu_icon"></div>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <div class="transition">
                <div class="sideBar">
                    <li><a href="about.html" class="selected">About</a></li>
                </div>  
            </div>
            <div class="transition">
                <div class="sideBar">
                    <li><a href="resume.html" class="selected">Resume</a></li>
                </div>  
            </div>
            <div class="transition">
                <div class="sideBar">
                    <li><a href="skills.html" class="selected">Skills</a></li>
                </div>  
            </div>
            <div class="transition">
                <div class="sideBar">
                    <li><a href="portfolio.html" class="selected">Portfolio</a></li>
                </div>  
            </div>
            <div class="transition">
                <div class="sideBar">
                    <li><a href="gallery.html" class="selected">Map&nbsp;Gallery</a></li>
                </div>  
            </div>
            <div class="transition">
                <div class="sideBar">
                    <li><a href="thesis.html" class="selected">Thesis</a></li>
                </div>  
            </div>
            <div class="transition">
                <div class="sideBar">
                    <li><a href="contact.html" class="selected">Contact</a></li>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </ul>
    </nav><!--end sidebar-->
            
    <div class="footer clearfix">
        <ul class="social clearfix">
            <li class ="email"><a href="mailto:md@outlook.com" class="email" target="_blank" data-title="Email"><img src="img/email.png"></a></li>
            <li class ="linkedin"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/pub/MD/b6/90b/26b?trk=pub-pbmap" class="linkedin" target="_blank" data-title="LinkedIn"><img src="img/linkedin.png"></a></li>
            <li class ="twitter"><a href="https://twitter.com/MD" class="twitter" target="_blank" data-title="Twitter"><img src="img/twitter.png"></a></li>
            <li class ="facebook"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/MD" class="facebook" target="_blank" data-title="Facebook"><img src="img/facebook.png"></a></li>
        </ul><!-- end social -->
        
        <div class="rights">
            <p>Copyright</p>
        </div><!-- end rights -->
    </div ><!-- end footer -->
</header><!-- end header -->
```

CSS:

```
@media (min-width:1100px) {

header {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 260px;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 0 0 0 50px;
    background: #FFFFFF; 
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 9999;
}

header .logo {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: -50px;
}

header nav ul {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 35px;
    margin-left: -15px;
    list-style: none;
}

header nav ul li {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

header nav ul li a {
    color: #000000;
    font-family: "raleway-regular", arial;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

header nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #8AE6B8;
}

header nav ul li a:active {
    color: #CC99FF;
}

.transition {
    width:50%; 
    height: 30px; 
    position: relative; 
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.transition:hover {
    width:100%; 
    height: 30px;
    position: relative; 
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.sideBar {
    width:75%; 
    height: 100%; 
    position: relative;
    padding:0px;
    margin-left:20%;    
}

header .footer {
    margin-top: 30%;
}
    
header ul.social {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);  /* For Webkit browsers */
    filter: gray;  /* For IE 6 - 9 */
    -webkit-transition: all .7s ease;  /* Transition for Webkit browsers */
}

    header ul.social li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 15px 15px 4px;
}

header ul.social li a {
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-position: 0 0;
}

header .rights p {
    color: #000000;
    font-family: "raleway-regular", arial;
    font-size: 11px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    line-height: 18px;
}

header .rights a {
    font-family: "raleway-bold", arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}
    
#menu_icon,
.close_menu {
    display: none;
}
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can check the position of the nav, and if it is above the top of the window then you can use:

```
position: fixed;
left: 0;
top: 0;
```

I couldn't really see where you are going in the jsfiddle link, but this is how I would go about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the nav fixed after scrolling at certain point on the page then you will have to write some JavaScript because it cannot be achieved through css.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var navpos = $('nav').offset();
    $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > navpos.top) {
        $('nav').addClass('fixed');
       }
       else {
         $('#nav').removeClass('fixed');
       }
    });
});
```

Css

```
.fixed {
   position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
}
```

Comment: I would appreciate if down voter left a comment so that I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check the scroll of the document with javascript and if it is not 0, then add this class to the nav:

```
.sticked{
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

And toggle the class like this:

```
var nav = document.querySelector(".nav");
window.addEventListener("scroll", handle_scroll);
function handle_scroll (e) {
    var scroll = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    if(scroll > 0){
        nav.classList.add("sticked");
    }else{
        nav.classList.remove("sticked");
    }
}
```